# Not able to hover over dropdown-menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have have made a site which has a dropdown menu. The rest of the web page doesn't change when the dropdown menu is called for because I have given the page `position:relative;`.

And the dropdown has a higher `z-index` than the page so it is visible at all times. The only problem I have is that I also want to change the `background-color` of the dropdown-menu when someone hovers over it.

But unfortunantely, when I hover over the dropddown, the browser thinks that I am hovering over the page and for some reason doesn't understand that I am actually hovering over the dropdown-menu. Can anyone please help me with this.

```css
#page {background-color;
    height: 2500px;
    width: 1600px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#dropdown {
    margin: 0px;
}

.dropdownitem {
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdownitem:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: white
}
```

I think I have come to understand what the problem is. The thing is that I have a div with

```
position:absolute
```

And inside that div there are a number of list items. Because my parent div has absolute positioning, the element has been taken out of document flow and when I hover over the list items, the :hover pseudo class does not work on those nested list items. So now I have found the reason, but what only rests is the solution, and I haven't yet found that.

Comment: Hi Arman. We're happy to help but you need to post your HTML and CSS code here so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Give us enough code that replicates the issue please. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: How is your website displaying the drop down menu on hover?

Comment: the display of the drop down menu is block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help

```css
ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

#page {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  text-align: center;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.mainmenu:hover>.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mainmenu,
.dropdownitem {
  width: 4em;
}

.dropdownitem {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdownitem:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <nav>
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li class="mainmenu">Main
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="dropdownitem">One</li>
          <li class="dropdownitem">Two</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```